# User name disappeared

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts, profile-page

Consider:

[image]

Until yesterday, my username was visible in this circle. But now it does not seem to be there. So I have to search my name under the 'users' section to go to my profile. Am I the only one facing this problem? What is the reason for this?

Comment: duplicate on [meta.SE]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368666/263383

Comment: What platform? Mobile phone? Android?

Comment: My username was showing up under that menu (although in a different place from before) on some other Stack Exchange sites less than half an hour ago, but it has since disappeared again.

Comment: Mine is still showing up

Comment: Yes @Peter ,mobile, android. I thought it was fixed. My name appears. And it has a new interface. Before, link to meta was shown near 'help, chat' in the above screenshot. Now it has a seperated link. And there are three lines 'username, physics, physics meta' : ) Before there were only two.

Comment: Now, my username is showing up on some sites but not others.  It's really weird.